# PHP Why does this loop endlessly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following function, that should loop between two dates, adding info to a mysql database. for some reason, it loops endlessly, and inserts rows starting at 1970

```
function blackout($start, $end, $class, $camper, $res) {
    $date=date ("Ymd", strtotime(strtotime($start)));
    while (strtotime($start) <= strtotime($end)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO availability VALUES ('','$date','$class','$camper','$res')");

        $date = date ("Ymd", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

    }
}
```

This is what I've called it with:

```
blackout(20150303,20150310,"classone",4,5);
```

So it should enter 7 rows into the database, but it puts hundreds of thousands if I dont close it.

Comment: because you don't change `$start` or `$end` anywhere

Comment: Where do you increment `$start` ?

Comment: Those values are not valid for `strtotime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop keeps updating `$date`, but the condition is based on the relation between `$start` and `$end`. Since they are not modified, the loop will go on forever.

Presumably, you intended to compare `$date` to `$end`:

```
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable $date instead of $start in the while condition